# PHP - Class not found, but is required

Tags: php, class, twitter-oauth, require

I am using the Abraham TwitterOAuth PHP SDK. I included the library at the top of `index.php` (File exists + I use `<?php`).

```
<?php
require 'inc/oauth/autoload.php';
var_dump(file_exists('inc/oauth/autoload.php')); //true
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

Below, between the HTML I include a `.php` file in a `div`, like so:

```
<?php include('div.php'); ?>
```

In this `div.php` file I instantiate the TwitterOAuth class, which throws an error:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['token']) && !empty($_COOKIE['token'])) {
        $token = objectToArray(json_decode($_COOKIE['token']));
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER, SECRET, $token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
```

This throws the error `Class 'TwitterOAuth' not found`.

**Note**

This was functioning BEFORE I moved the code to `div.php`. I however need it to be seperate because in the future I will refresh the div using JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class uses the `Abraham\TwitterOAuth` namespace - so you have to include them or use the fqn (fully qualified classname)

```
    $connection = new \Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER, SECRET, $token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it (will accept in ~6 minutes). Any reason why included files ignore `use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;` from `index.php`? Because this same code worked when the code of `div.php` was directly in `index.php`. Why doesn't it work with includes?

Comment: because class aliases declared with `use` are only known inside the same file.

Comment: Ah I see on php.net: `Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.`. Thank You!